# Approximation with Neural Network not working, predicts a constant value throughout the domain

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm writing a script to infer a plane from 2D data. So far, this is what I came up with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def interp(dataxy,dataz,prediction,plot):
    model=tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
                           tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.relu),
                            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=None)])
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
    model.fit(dataxy,dataz,epochs=100,verbose=False)

    if plot:
        iter_max=10
        x=y=np.arange(0,1+1/iter_max,1/iter_max)
        Z=np.zeros((iter_max+1,iter_max+1))

        for iter_i in x:
            for iter_j in y:

                ponto = [iter_i,iter_j]
                [aux] = model.predict([ponto])
                Z[int(iter_max*iter_i)][int(iter_max*iter_j)]=aux
                
        X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        Z=Z.reshape(iter_max+1,iter_max+1)
        
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        # plt.xlabel('input')
        # plt.ylabel("output")
        ax.scatter([dataxy[i][0] for i in range(0,len(dataxy))],[dataxy[i][1] for i in range(0,len(dataxy))], zs=dataz, s=20, color='black')
        ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, label="predictions")
    
    return model.predict([prediction])
```

And the training data is given by:

```
xx=[[0,0],[0,1],[0,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0],[1,1]]
and
yy=[2.6,0.9,1.2,-0.05,1.1,2.3,-1.42]
```

The thing is, it's only returning a constant value, about 2.4, throughout the whole domain ([0,1]x[0,1]). What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Here's the final code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def interpv3(dataxy,dataz,prediction,plot):
    model=tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.relu, input_dim = 2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=None))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
    model.fit(dataxy,dataz,epochs=100,verbose=False)

    if plot:
        iter_max=10
        x=y=np.arange(0,1+1/iter_max,1/iter_max)
        Z=np.zeros((iter_max+1,iter_max+1))

        for iter_i in x:
            for iter_j in y:
                
                ponto = [iter_i,iter_j]
                [aux] = model.predict([ponto])
                Z[int(iter_max*iter_i)][int(iter_max*iter_j)]=aux
                
        X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        Z=Z.reshape(iter_max+1,iter_max+1)
        
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        ax.scatter([dataxy[i][0] for i in range(0,len(dataxy))],
                   [dataxy[i][1] for i in range(0,len(dataxy))],
                   dataz, s=20, color='black')
        ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, label="predictions")
    
    return model.predict([prediction])
```

The difference was that I explicitly said that the input_dim was 2, instead of just adding a Dense layer with 2 neurons.
Needs some tinkering with number of hidden neurons and learning_rate, though.

Answer (score 0):

The NN failed to learn a function from your data. There are two problems:

1. As you can see in your data, two **identical** samples are corresponding to two different expected values.
2. The amount of data is insufficient for the model to learn.

I suggest collecting more data first, or you could do a simple data augmentation by adding a small random noise to your inputs.

Comment: The system I'm modeling is given by 2 binary variables (that's why there's 0s and 1s in the xy plane, and any combination of them is a 'state'), and there must be multiple entries (z values) related to the same state, so I think it's impossible for me to not have identical samples corresponding to different values. That's why I'm referring to the problem as an approximation, not an interpolation. But thanks for the reply, I'll work on that.